# How to eliminate the white highlights?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, selections

How do I tone down the extreme white that shows up along the side of his neck, his ear, and on his knuckles? Adjusting the contrast doesn't seem to help.

[image: man with odd highlights]

EDIT:

(Some background information on what I've tried)

I tried:

Like mentioned above, adjusting the contrast and brightness. No luck.

Then, I selected the brush tool, selected the "color dodge" mode (on the panel at the top of the screen), however, it affected nearby pixels.

Using the color replacement tool lead to a similar result.

I read somewhere that you should try using levels or curves, but it when I tried the first time, it didn't work for me. I was adjusting the position of the gray, white and black swatches underneath the histogram, but that didn't help. Jagged black outlines grew around the white highlights when I tried to adjust the white to a grayer color.

In desperation, I even tried putting a grey cut out the same shape as the man in a layer beneath, and tried painting dark grey onto the mask I applied on the top layer. Again, other pixels became grayer too.

However, thanks to all the comments suggesting levels/curves, I figured I was doing it wrong. On my second try, it worked. (Instead of the swatches, I shifted the a slider on a palette, and the white was toned down to grey.)

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE. What else have you tried? Where else have you researched?

Comment: Have you tried using curves?

Comment: Easiest way would be to use a curves or levels adjustment layer. [Like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9323o.gif)

Comment: It is a very basic but valid question.

Comment: I don't remember the specific sites (I'll hold onto them next time), but I was at quite a few places. I tried painting over the highlights using the brush and color dodge mode, but just like what happened with the color replacement tool, it affected other pixels. I tried using levels, but it didn't work for me the first time - I was adjusting the grey, white and black swatches, but that didn't help. All the votes in the levels direction suggested I was doing it wrong, and on my second try, it worked. Should I still edit my question?

Comment: Try [photo.se] instead.

Comment: @habudu Please do! With these edits, it is a very valid question I'd upvote!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many solutions to this but the best is a Curves Adjustment Layer with a mask.

Lower the White Output like so:

[image]

Then invert the mask (it was already inverted in the above screenshot) by clicking on the White square in your Layer Panel and hitting <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>

Now with a small brush and low flow and/or opacity paint in the highlights.

[image]

You can then adjust the Curves or the Opacity of the Curves Adjustment to tune it further.